# How to set keyboard layout used to enter password on an encrypted filesystem?

Tags: debian, boot, lvm, keyboard-layout

After my upgrade to Debian 6 (Squeeze), the keyboard layout used to enter the password of encrypted filesystem has been changed.  How can I revert it back to previous one?

My understanding is that, before the encrypted filesystem gets unlocked, the only active partition is `/boot`, therefore such a setting should be there somewhere.  However, after extensive Internet searching and grepping `/boot`, I've not been able to find it.

I've also tried to reconfigure the keyboard layout used by the console, running:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

...and:

```
dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

...with no effect.

Comment: If you have an encrypted root filesystem, you'll have to get setting the keymap to be part of the initramfs. I don't think thats done by default. Off-topic here, though; belongs on unix I suspect.

Comment: Thanks Caleb.  That was it.

I did this [link](http://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard#Set_Keyboard_Layout_in_initramfs), and it worked.

Comment: @Elna: Please add an short answer below with a summary of how you fixed the problem and after the timeout mark it as "accepted". That is how SE sites keep track of what answers are solved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to customize your `initramfs`.  Take a look at the `update-initramfs` manpage as one possible starting point.